# How to test useRef's current, using jest and enzyme?

Tags: jestjs, enzyme, use-ref

I have a Demo.tsx file,which has the below code:

```
const aRef = useRef() as RefObject<HTMLDivElement>;
const bRef = useRef() as RefObject<HTMLDivElement>;
const a = 10;
const b = 10;
useEffect(() => {
  if (!!aRef.current && !!bRef.current) {
    const temp = functionRefCall({ARef:aref,Bref:bref,A:a,B:b})
  }
}, [aRef, bRef]);
return (

      <div className="aRef-container" ref={aRef} />
      <div className="bRef-container" ref={bRef} />

  </div>

);
```

Below is code for my functionRefCall.ts file:

```
export interface myInterface {
  Aref: HTMLElement;
  Bref: HTMLElement;
  A: number;
  B:  number;
}

export default (
  i18n: i18n,
  {Aref,Bref,A,B }: myInterface,
) => {
return a+b;
}
```

How will i test that if my ref's are not null,the functionRefCall is being called and it returns a+b